# NSString Category for better percent escaping

Tags: encoding, nsstring, urlencode, percent-encoding

I wrote a little NSString category with a better implementation of percent escaping for one of my projects:
@im

```
plementation NSString (Escaping)
- (NSString *)stringByAddingSafePercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
    NSRange wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [self length]);
    NSMutableString *escaping = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:encoding]];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@"%24" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"%3B" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"%2D" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"%40" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@"%09" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"%23" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"%3C" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"%3E" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%22" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"%0A" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    NSString *escaped = [NSString stringWithString:escaping];

    return escaped;
}
@end
```

In this one project it works GREAT and I love to use it. But when I port it to another project, that code throughs an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Could I make something better in that code?

Comment: What's wrong with [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes)?

Comment: I used it a wile ago. But I got (null) every time. But what's wrong with my category? And my original question is not solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my problem by accident:

Since the string effectively changes its length when replacing one characters by three characters, the string length changes with every replace. So the correct implementation for the category would be:

```
@implementation NSString (Escaping)
- (NSString *)stringByAddingSafePercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
    NSRange wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [self length]);
    NSMutableString *escaping = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:encoding]];
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@"%24" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"%3B" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"%2D" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"%40" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@"%09" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"%23" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"%3C" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"%3E" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%22" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [escaping length]);
    [escaping replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"%0A" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
    NSString *escaped = [NSString stringWithString:escaping];

    return escaped;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
NSRange wholeString = NSMakeRange(0, [self length]-1);
```

You would get 'bad access' if your replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range: method iterates past the last character in the string.

Or you could use something like this for your replacement methods which already figures on iterating over the whole length. I am not sure what the default search option is however:

```
escaping = [escaping stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"$" withString:@"%24"];
```

Comment: I somehow fixed it. I think I had a double implementation through imports or something like this. Your implementation not correct, though. NSMutableString has no selector `stringByReplacingOrrurencesOfString:withString`, you have to use NSStringCompareOptions and NSRange too.

Comment: Hi Julian,
NSMutableString inherits from NSString which does have that method. They added it in 10.5. See the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: How wow — I just saw that I forgot to claim I was talking about iOS, I'm really sorry! :)

Comment: No worries. I have been working more recently on the OSX side of the world, so I too forget that iOS does things differently! Glad to hear you figured it out. I actually bookmarked this page as a percent escapes equivalents reference. You hit most of the ones I care about!